# Count total values after CountDistinct

Tags: count, sum, unique, distinct, distinct-values

i created a table in which i want to see all the resources that were used on 1 day, for different missions. It's possible that a resource executed more than 1 mission / day. that's why i used an expression with CountDistinct to only show the unique number of resources, used in 1 day for all the missions.

Now as a next step , i want to see what the average number of unique resources is, for a selected time period.
Unfortunately i am not able to use a count or sum expression on the CountDistinct-expression.
If i execute a sum function it gives me the total number of unique values, spread accross the time period, but i want to make a sum of the resources used per day.

fex i have 3 resources , on day 1 i use resource A for 5 missions on day 2 i use resource A & B for 6 missions. so that makes 11 missions on 2 days, and 3 resources ( A + A + B ).

[image]

[image]

so i want to count the 82+92+100+90+91+92. How do i get the sum of these values ?

any suggestions on how to fix this please?

MANY THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, created 2 extra datasets to pull the unique values / day.
Added a lookup function in one of the two tablix to compare the values on the same dates ( dates in both datesets ) = > unique values per day. Afterwards made the sum of the values and divided by number of days to get get average unique values / per day.